# Parse.com enter more informations for sign in

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am  creating an android application for school which let people sign in, for this i used Parse.

My activities for signing in are in this way:
- the first activity, the student enter the email address and passeword and retape passeword, when he push the button, parse verify the email if it doesn't exist if the signing in is secusseful the second activity start.

-The second activity containt text field to complete the profil (FirstName, LastName, Age....).

In Parse.com :
In the Users class I've add new columns (FirstName, LastName,Age...)

My problem is that when the user complete the profil and accept, the data of FirstName, LastName...etc will be add in the Users class of Parse.com to complete the row of the current user signing in.

I've used in the second activity SignInBackground but it bug caus it demand a username (wich is already entered in the first activity), I also used SaveInBackground and also ParseObject but it create a new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling `signUpInBackground(SignUpCallback callback)` in your first `Activity`.

Here's the Parse documentation about that method:

> public void signUpInBackground(SignUpCallback callback)
>   Signs up a new user. You should call this instead of ParseObject.save() for new ParseUsers. This will create a new ParseUser on the server, and also persist the session on disk so that you can access the user using ParseUser.getCurrentUser().
>   A username and password must be set before calling signUp.
>
> This is preferable to using ParseUser.signUp(), unless your code is already running from a background thread.
>
> Parameters:
>   callback - callback.done(user, e) is called when the signUp completes.

So, what you can see is that this method both **registers** the user with Parse and **logs in** the user, persisting that login session to disk.

Therefore, when you get to your next `Activity`, you have no need to sign up or log in. You can simply get the new values from the user and then access the current user (`ParseUser.currentUser()`), adding the values to that object in a manner like this:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.currentUser();
user.put("attribute1", "value1");
user.put("attribute2", "value2");
user.put("attribute3", "value3");
user.put("attribute4", "value4");    
// And so on...
user.saveInBackground(); // You might want to implement a SaveCallback there
```

***FYI:*** The `saveInBackground()` method is inherited from `ParseObject`.

Comment: thank you, i already did it, yes i was using parseobject and not parseuser

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly it is that you don't have the data available for the username when you are calling saveInBackground in Activity 2. If this is the case I think the best option would be to pass the data you need (username etc) in the intent when you load the second activity.

To add the username to the intent you would do something like this.

```
String usernameText = "";
Intent ii=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
ii.putExtra("username", usernameText);
startActivity(ii);
```

Then to retreive the username in OnCreate method of Activity 2 you would do something like:

```
Intent iin= getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

if(b!=null)
{
    String username =(String) b.get("username");
}
```

Obviously in my solution, I have assumed that you will retrieve the username from an EditText, but haven't put this into my code, as I have assumed you know how to do this already. Also in Activity 2 once you retrieve the username you will need to store it as a global variable, so that it can be used once the user finishes filling out the form on Activity 2.